# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in

Tags: php, mysql, fatal-error

I have quiz website and I'm working on adding question and images, and every couple minute site stop working and show me this message

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in /storage/ssd3/561/18376561/public_html/configs/connection.php on line 48

and this the code

```
];

# Tables' Prefix
define('prefix', 'pl_');

# No need to change anything bellow this line
$db = new mysqli($connect['HOSTNAME'], $connect['USERNAME'], $connect['PASSWORD'], $connect['DATABASE']);
if($db->connect_errno){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $db->connect_errno . ") " . $db->connect_error;
        exit;
}


$sql_mode = $db->query("SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;");
$rs_mode = $sql_mode->fetch_assoc();
```

I want to continue to add questions and image as much as I want without interrupt me like this and waiting an hour to back working and keep repeating happen this problem over and over

Comment: try removing the `;` at the end

Comment: The "boolean" is because your query did not execute, it returned "false". You should check the query worked before trying to retrieve results from it.

Comment: so how to fix droopsnoot

Comment: Enable exceptions in `mysqli`. This makes errors impossible to ignore.

Comment: plase guys if any one write how code should be to fix this problem